# How to interface IO Link devices without any gateway/additional circuit

Tags: raspberry-pi, interface, io, peripheral

I am planning to use a distance sensing device like [this distance sensor](https://www.sensopart.com/en/products/distance-sensors/distance-sensors/ft-25-ra-170-pnsul-m4m.html) with a mini computer like the Raspberry Pi or the Jetson boards. I read that the interfacing requires additional gateway like [this](https://www.pi4industry.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/MICA-R_spec_sheet_IO-Link_20200210-EN_web.pdf).

Due to the reasons like cost saving, etc, is it possible to avoid this gateway... such that the analog output of the sensor can be interfaced directly with the mini computer ?

Comment: Mini computers were called this when they were desktop size. ;) micros are used now

Comment: But then micros may become mini when the nano computers come

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your computer has an ADC (analog to digital converter), then it has an ADC; if not, then not. There's not really much to answer here – you will have to read the specifications of the computers you're interested in and decide whether they do what you need. No way around that.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, you want to use the sensor with I/O Link connectivity and not Anaog output like Marcus mentionned ?

IO-Link is a short distance, bi-directional, digital, point-to-point, wired, industrial communications networking standard used for connecting digital sensors and actuators to a PLC or another type of industrial fieldbus. It is very convenient to simplify cable management in a complex machine because you connect only one cable to a sensor or actuator and they can be locally centralized to a hub which then goes back to the main PLC of the machine. The catch is that those cable contain 3 wires with a complex encoding on the data cable.

Here is an architecture example :
[image: I/O Link architecture, from : https://comtrol.com/wp-content/uploads/IO-Link-Protocols-2019-01.png]
(https://comtrol.com/wp-content/uploads/IO-Link-Protocols-2019-01.png)

The gateway your are mentionning has the role of this hub/master which consist in converting the I/O-Link protocol to any other protocol. In the case of the Raspberry PI or the Jetson, it would probably be Ethernet TCP/IP via RJ45.
Those hubs are rather expensive and at this time I know only a few opensource initiative to circumvent that.

For raspberry pi you could look at [this project](https://bfh.easydocmaker.ch/search/abstract/2056/) or [that one](https://github.com/openiolink) and for arduino [that one](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-662-59895-5_2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I developed an extension for Raspberry Pi that is able to do the perform the task. It connects up to two IO-Link devices and comes with a software stack that provides also easy integration over a binary TCP interface. The project is open source, the software is based on the I-Link stack from RT-Labs.

[image: Master application and interfaces]
Currently I am running a campaign on CrowdSupply for this project. So if you are interested, here is more information:
[www.pinetek-networks.com/iol-hat](https://www.pinetek-Networks.com/iol-hat)

I would appreciate if you would register for updates. The subscriptions will move the project closer to realization.